# Why can't I use filter in custom controller with Vapor 4?

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I want to add a route to get matched data by searching for a specific string. I added the route into `routes(_:)` in **routes.swift**.

```swift
import Fluent
import Vapor

func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
  // route "api/acronyms/search?term=The+string+searched
  app.get("search") { req -> EventLoopFuture<[Acronym]> in
    guard let searchTerm = req.query[String.self, at: "term"] else {
      throw Abort(.badRequest)
    }

    return Acronym.query(on: app.db)
      .group(.or) { group in
        group
          .filter(\.$short == searchTerm)
          .filter(\.$long == searchTerm)
      }
      .all()
  }
}
```

And this works. I want to move it into controller. So I created a handler function in the controller.

```swift
import Vapor
import Fluent

struct AcronymsController: RouteCollection {
  let app: Application

  func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
    routes.get("search", use: search)
  }
  
  func search(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Acronym]> {
    guard let searchTerm = req.query[String.self, at: "term"] else {
            throw Abort(.badRequest)
          }

          return Acronym.query(on: app.db)
            .filter(\Acronym.$short == searchTerm)
            .filter(\Acronym.$long == searchTerm)
            .all()
  }
}
```

But I got Swift Compiler Error: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'KeyPath<Acronym, FieldProperty<Acronym, String>>' and 'String'`.

Why `filter` with operator `==` doesn't work in the controller?

**Environment**

- Vapor 4.27.1 (toolbox 18.2.1)
- Swift 5.2.4
- macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: I tested the above code and it is working for me, no build errors. I changed the Acronym model to a model in my project to test it, so maybe the issue is with something in the Acronym model, could you please post the content of Acronym model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `import Fluent` in the controller file so the compiler can see the operator overloads fire the query